# Checking for XML declaration in VB6

Tags: xml, vb6

Firstly apologies...I haven't used VB6 (or any strain of VB for that matter) for a very long time.

I had the following code

```
nodRoot.appendChild TempTableData.childNodes(0)
```

That gives the error "This operation can not be performed with a Node of type XMLDECL."

So I loop through the Child nodes as follows to not append the node if it is the XML declaration.

```
      Dim nod As IXMLDOMNode
      For Each nod In TempTableData.childNodes()
        If Not nod.baseName = "xml" Then
          nodRoot.appendChild nod
        End If
      Next nod
```

Which works ok but seems an inelegant way of checking for an XML Node declaration. So what I'd like to achieve is to check against node type = XMLDECL but I can't find a way of doing this.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you I'm dredging the depths of ancient memory, but I have a vague recollection that in the COM XML implementations, the XML Declaration node had `nodeType = NODE_PROCESSING_INSTRUCTION (= 7)`.

So if removing all processing instructions is OK you could filter on that, otherwise you'll still have to check the baseName, so you don't gain anything.